# Best way to fix burnt PCB trace?

Tags: pcb, repair, trace

So I accidentally burnt a PCB trace and I'm trying to fix it with a wire + some solder. The PCB trace clearly connects two metal pins.

My question is, would it be better to completely bypass the trace and solder the wire from one pin to another? 
Or to solder the wire from the good part of the trace, over the burnt part, to the other side of burnt part (so still using the good parts of the trace)?

I don't have that many materials, so I can't really do any fancy repairs.

Thanks!

Comment: It should go without saying that pictures are necessary here.

Comment: You should find [this page very handy](http://www.circuitrework.com/guides/4-0.shtml) IPC and JEDEC conforming PCB repair procedures. About 10 different ways to fix a trace there

Comment: You need photos and some explanation of what the trace did. For example, if the trace carried mains voltage to a relay then you should try to maintain proper clearances for safety. Laying a bare wire down the middle of where the trace was (and perhaps tack it down with some dollar store epoxy) might be the right approach. Or bypass it with a suitable insulated wire. The gauge of the wire has to be sufficient for the purpose (current or voltage drop) in any case. There are other special situations, it just depends.

Comment: @crasic good link. It was very informative

Answer (score 2):

Either way would work.

I'd normally try to just bypass the damaged part, following the damaged track.  However, is it sometimes hard, particularly with very narrow tracks or heavy solder mask, to get the repair wire to stick to the track, so it my be easier to bypass the track altogether and go pin-to-pin.  (I use #30 wire wrap wire for such repairs (or error corrections)).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a wire to bypass the whole trace. Scraping the solder mask and the heat from the soldering iron can stress the already damaged trace, and could lead to the trace lifting, at the solder time or in future.

Also scraping the solder mask will let the copper unprotected from air moisture, and can cause oxidation in the future.

But seeing the extension of the damage, and the traces involved, we can give you a better suggestion and/or solution. Post a photo of the damaged area so we can see it.